# Python - subtraction inside rolling window

Tags: python, rolling-computation

> I need to make subtractions inside red frames as [20-10,60-40,100-70]
> that results in [10,20,30]

[image]

> Current code makes subtractions but I don't know how to define red frames

```
seq = [10, 20, 40, 60, 70, 100]
window_size = 2
for i in range(len(seq) - window_size+1):
    x=seq[i: i + window_size]
    y=x[1]-x[0]
    print(y)
```

Comment: `[seq[i+1]-seq[i] for i in range(0, len(seq), 2)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build a quick solution using the fact that `seq[0::2]` will give you every other element of `seq` starting at zero. So you can compute `seq[1::2] - seq[0::2]` to get this result.

Without using any packages you could do:

```
seq = [10, 20, 40, 60, 70, 100]
sub_seq = [0]*(len(seq)//2)
for i in range(len(sub_seq)):
    sub_seq[i] = seq[1::2][i] - seq[0::2][i]

print(sub_seq)
```

Instead you could use Numpy. Using the numpy array object you can subtract the arrays rather than explicitly looping:

```
import numpy as np
seq = np.array([10, 20, 40, 60, 70, 100])
sub_seq = seq[1::2] - seq[0::2]

print(sub_seq)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using numpy which might be useful if you have to process large amounts of data in a short time. We select values based on whether their index is even (`index % 2 == 0`) or odd (`index % 2 != 0`).

```
import numpy as np

seq = [10, 20, 40, 60, 70, 100]
seq = np.array(seq)

index = np.arange(len(seq))
seq[index % 2 != 0] - seq[index % 2 == 0]
```